# java- repaint() method is misbehaving - 2?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, jlayeredpane, null-layout-manager

This question is an extension of [java- repaint() method is misbehaving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618571/java-repaint-method-is-misbehaving)
**(Reading it, is optional)**

I am working on a `Music Player`

I am using a `JSlider` as seek bar and using a `JLabel` to draw text on screen, such as song name.

I am new to `Graphics2D`

Here's the minimized code:

```
public class JSliderDemo extends JFrame
{
    
JLabel label;
JSlider seek = new JSlider();
int  y = 10;    

public JSliderDemo()
{
 setSize(400, 400);
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 
 createWindow();
 setVisible(true);
 startThread();
}        
    
public void createWindow()
{
 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 panel.setOpaque(true);
 panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
 panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
 
 JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
 layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
 
 label = new Component();
 label.setSize(300, 300);
 
 createSlider();

 layeredPane.add(seek, new Integer(50));
 layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(100));
 
 panel.add(layeredPane);
 add(panel);
}        

protected void createSlider()
{
 seek.setUI(new SeekBar(seek, 300, 10, new Dimension(20, 20), 5, 
           Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.RED, Color.RED));
 seek.setOrientation(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
 seek.setOpaque(false);
 seek.setLocation(10, 50);
 seek.setSize(300, 20);
 seek.setMajorTickSpacing(0);
 seek.setMinorTickSpacing(0);
 seek.setMinimum(0);
 seek.setMaximum(1000);    
 seek.setBorder(new MatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, Color.CYAN));
}        

protected void startThread()
{
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
 @Override
 public void run()
 {
  try
  {
   while(true)
   {
    if(y == label.getHeight()){y = 1;}   
    label.repaint();
    y += 1;
   
    Thread.sleep(100);   
   }    
  }   
  catch(Exception ex){}
 }
 });
 
 thread.start();
}        
        
protected class Component extends JLabel
{
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
 Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) g;
 gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
 
 gr.setColor(Color.RED);
 gr.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 16));
 gr.drawString("Song Name", 50, y);
 
 gr.dispose();
}       
}          

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 new JSliderDemo();
}
    
}
```

The problem is, when I call `repaint()` for `JLabel` it automatically repaints `JSlider` with it even though `JSlider` is not included in `JLabel`.

Output :

```
Slider re-painted
Slider re-painted
Slider re-painted
Slider re-painted
Slider re-painted
Slider re-painted.........
```

Now if I remove `label.repaint()` from the `Thread`, then the `JSlider` is not re-painted.

Output:

```
Slider re-painted
Slider re-painted
```

Is the `repaint()` method supposed to work like this?

In my last question, I was told to use `Layout Manager` and when I did use `GridLayout` just for checking if it's the solution, then it worked!

Only `JLabel` was repainted.

But I want to overlap `JLabel` on `JSlider`, so I thought of using `JLayeredPane`. And now, the problem is back.

How can I solve this?

**Bottom Line** : How can I overlap `JLabel` on `JSlider` without leading to `repaint()` method misbehave ?

OR

Does the `repaint()` method work like this?

Comment: I think swing's RepaintManager can also consider dirty regions, and since you're handling the size and location of components yourself, is there a chance they overlap and cause the RepaintManager to repaint all components in the dirty region?

Comment: *The problem is, when I call repaint() for JLabel it automatically repaints JSlider with it even though JSlider is not included in JLabel.* - why is that a problem?. A JLabel is transparent. When you paint a transparent component, Swing first needs to repaint the parent component of the label that is not transparent so the background is painted properly.

Comment: Why are you extending JLabel to paint a text String? If you want animation then use a regular JLabel and change the location of the label.

Comment: @camickr I don't understand!  In this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62631255/13824394     you said, _You should not be setting the location of components. That is the job of the layout manager_ , but here you are suggesting me to change the location of `JLabel` manually to simulate animation.

Comment: The bounds of your label and slider overlap. This swing will need to repaint both of them when repainting the label, as repainting the label alone could paint over the part of the slider. Note that even though the label is repainted it will only actually repaint the overlapping part with the slider (so might actually won’t do anything).

Comment: @AnrewFred, we can only answer a question based on the context of the question. In the context of the other question you ask about using setLocation() and revalidate(). Those two methods should not be used together. So the answer was given based on the question. Note don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer. This question is different as it is about animation. So the solution for animation is different.

Comment: Or if you want to do custom painting then you would extend JComponent or JPanel (but not JLabel), Then you would build logic into the component to start a Swing Timer to animate the painting of the text. The functionality should be contained within the component, not external to the component.

Comment: @weisj, the overlapping is not the only reason the slider is repainted. As I already suggested earlier, because they overlap and because the label is opaque, the background of the parent component (ie. the slider) also needs to be repainted.

Comment: @camickr I think I wasn't quite clear enough with my explanation. The fact that the slider also need to be repainted is that the label os opaque, you are right to correct me on that. However the calling the slider the "parent" of the label is quite wrong in this scenario as their common parent is the `JLayeredPane`. Them having overlaping bounds is quite crucial to the slider being repainted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, the reason for your `JSlider` being repainted is that it has overlapping bounds with the `JLabel`. Even though your label doesn't paint over the area of the slider swing will still mark the overlapping area as dirty (i.e. the overlapping part of the slider will need to be repainted) because swing doesn't know that you are only painting in one part of the component.

To reduce the amount of repaints you will need to make the size of your `JLabel` smaller. Preferably only as large as it needs to be by invoking its `getPreferredSize()` method. You'll then be able to move the text by moving the location of the label.

Also you shouldn't be doing updates to the gui in a plain `Thread`. Use `javax.swing.Timer` instead. It ensures that all updates to the gui happen on the swing event thread, which is where they should be made.

After making these adjustments to your code the slider is only repainted while the label is actually visually over the slider.

```java
public class JSliderDemo extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(JSliderDemo::new);
    }

    private final JLabel label = new CustomLabel();

    public JSliderDemo() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        createWindow();
        setVisible(true);
        startTimer();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));

        label.setLocation(0, 0);
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());

        layeredPane.add(createSlider(), Integer.valueOf(50));
        layeredPane.add(label, Integer.valueOf(100));

        panel.add(layeredPane);
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    protected JSlider createSlider() {
        JSlider seek = new CustomSlider();
        seek.setOrientation(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
        seek.setOpaque(false);
        seek.setLocation(10, 50);
        seek.setSize(300, 20);
        seek.setMajorTickSpacing(0);
        seek.setMinorTickSpacing(0);
        seek.setMinimum(0);
        seek.setMaximum(1000);
        seek.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        return seek;
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        new Timer(100, e -> {
            int y = label.getY();
            int maxY = label.getParent().getHeight();
            if (y == maxY) {
                y = -label.getHeight();
            }
            label.setLocation(label.getX(), y + 1);
            label.repaint();
        }).start();
    }

    private static class CustomLabel extends JLabel {

        protected CustomLabel() {
            setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 16));
            setText("Song Name");
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("Painting Label");
        }
    }

    protected static class CustomSlider extends JSlider {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("Painting Slider");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *the reason for your JSlider being repainted is that it has overlapping bounds with the JLabel* - That is not completely true as I tried to explain. 1) slow down the animation to 250  . 2) Make the label opaque. 3) The slider will not be repainted as the label enters and completely covers the slider. This is because Swing doesn't care what component is below the the label. It optimizes the painting when the component is opaque. So the reason the slider is painted as the label moves over the slider is because the label is transparent.

Comment: 4) However, as the label moves  out the bottom of the slider both the slider and label are repainted because Swing needs to repaint the previous area that the label covered of the slider. 5) Also, note that `label.repaint()` is not required. Swing components will repaint themselves when a property of the component is changed.